# Tags - Emulation vs. Virtualization

Tags: discussion, tags

There seem to be two types of questions that are appearing under the [emulation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emulation) tag.

One group of questions centers around using the Raspberry Pi to emulate something else, such as the Atari 2600 console.

Another group of questions concerns questions about the process of virtualizing the Raspberry Pi itself on another PC (for example, on a Linux desktop).

I would like to suggest that these two questions have two separate, specific tags.

- For questions about systems that you're trying to run on the Raspberry Pi, use
  the [emulation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emulation) tag.
- For questions about virtualizing the Raspberry Pi and running it on other
  hardware, use the [virtualization](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/virtualization) tag.

Any feedback?

Answer (score 5):

## Chat Discussion

@Zoot, @AlexChamberlain, @BryanDunsmore, @Jivings and @Mana discussed this in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3748/conversation/meta-discussion-241). We decided that, whilst it would be nice to separate the emulation of the Raspberry Pi on another box from the emulation of another box on a Raspberry Pi, this can't be achieved using [emulation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emulation) and [virtualization](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/virtualization).

The problem is emulation of the Raspberry Pi on another box is the virtualisation of a Raspberry Pi on another box, just as the emulation of another box on a Raspberry Pi is the virtualisation of another box on a Raspberry Pi. Arbitrarily picking [emulation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emulation) for one and [virtualization](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/virtualization) for the other would lead to confusion and constant work for the mods and trusted users.

Comment: Great, now lets get emulating.

Comment: I have a Raspberry Pi.